Getting GCP's Sensitive Data Protection service to send security events to Pub/Sub
In Google Cloud Platform (GCP), I am in the Security Command Center (SCC) and Sensitive Data Protection (SDP) services. I have configured SDP to scan a Cloud Storage bucket daily, and configured it with the Info Type I am particularly interested in it reporting (social security numbers).
So far it seems to be working, yesterday I had intentionally uploaded a doc to that bucket that contained, in plaintext, a fake SSN (123-45-6789). I just took a look in SDP, and sure enough, it flagged it in a profile containing Highly Sensitive data -- nice!
I would now like SDP to event whenever it scans and finds Highly Sensitive data (such as docs containing SSNs) and send a message to a specific Pub/Sub topic. But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do it! Can anyone share with me the "secret sauce" to getting SDP to event to Pub/Sub?!?
